# MySQL: Shouldn't these two DATE queries be the same?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this query, it tells me what order has expired, immediately after it expires.

```
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    orders as ord
  WHERE
    DATE_ADD(paid_on, INTERVAL ord.duration HOUR) < NOW()
    AND DATE(DATE_ADD(paid_on, INTERVAL ord.duration HOUR)) BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    AND DATE(NOW())
)
UNION
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      orders as ord
    WHERE
      DATE_ADD(paid_on, INTERVAL ord.extended_duration HOUR) < NOW()
      AND DATE(
        DATE_ADD(paid_on, INTERVAL ord.extended_duration HOUR)
      ) BETWEEN DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
      AND DATE(NOW())
  )
```

I have decided to optimize it by rewriting it like this

```
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    orders as ord
  WHERE
    DATE_ADD(ord.paid_on, INTERVAL ord.duration HOUR) < NOW()
    AND DATE_ADD(ord.paid_on, INTERVAL ord.duration HOUR) BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    AND CURDATE()
)
UNION
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      orders as ord
    WHERE
      DATE_ADD(ord.paid_on, INTERVAL ord.extended_duration HOUR) < NOW()
      AND DATE_ADD(ord.paid_on, INTERVAL ord.extended_duration HOUR) BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
      AND CURDATE()
  )
```

All I did is using `CURDATE()` instead of `DATE(NOW())`, but the queries are retrieving different results, the first query is working correctly,  the second query sometimes waits 24h before showing something as expired. [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ffUvcA57w9vQSqNJp182qK/1)

Comment: your dbfiddle code will not run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND  DATE_ADD(ord.paid_on, INTERVAL ord.extended_duration HOUR)
```

is a DATETIME, which might be in the middle of today.

```
BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

excludes anything after midnight this morning.

Please provide the order that is miscategorized.

Comment: I'll show you the orders that are miscategorized in few hours if the issue persists. I'm thinking not to change the first query because I did not see any performance gains by using `curdate()` instead of `date(now())`

Comment: Perhaps `AND` should be `OR`?  I don't understand your 4 tests.